# Flutter: How to use widgets with abstract constructors

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created a Drawer widget in flutter, but the DrawerHeader widget I've listed as one of its children takes up more vertical space than I want.

From DrawerHeader's properties [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DrawerHeader-class.html), it looks like the `margin` property might be responsible for size, but I'm stuck on how to use the `EdgeInsetsGeometry` widget since its constructor is abstract.

I've included code that is similar to mine below:

```
return Scaffold(
    drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: <Widget>[
              // want to use margin property in DrawerHeader widget
              DrawerHeader(child: Text("Header"))
          ],
        )
    )
    ...
);
```

Comment: When you look at the documentation for [`EdgeInsetsGeometry`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/EdgeInsetsGeometry-class.html), pay attention to the "Implementers" section that lists classes that implement the specified interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EdgeInsetsGeometry` is just an abstract class.

One concrete implementation is `EdgeInsets`:

```dart
DrawerHeader(
  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
)
```